# what will be the output of following code in PHP?

Tags: php

```
for($x++ ; $x==2 ; $x=2) 
print "In the for loop" ; 
print "After the loop" ;
```

There is no scope assigned. The answer is

```
In the for loop After the loop.
```

And I didn't get the idea that how it is.?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is not scope assigned"?

Comment: The code will not print **In the for loop**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go through [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) you will find all the expressions are wrong -

For `for($x++ ; $x==2 ; $x=2)`

> The first `$x++` `0`.  - Incrementing an undefined variable sets it to 1, because it converts null to 0 when it's used in an arithmetic context..
>
> The second `$x==2` will return `false` and the iteration will not be executed.
>
> The third `$x=2` will be executed at the end of each iteration.

So, the iteration will never be executed as `$x==2` is always `false`.

And the output will be  **After the loop**

Comment: Incrementing an undefined variable sets it to `1`, because it converts `null` to `0` when it's used in an arithmetic context.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Did not know that. :)

Comment: Rather than the expressions being wrong, I would say they are just misused.  They are done in a way that is either not intended or done in such a way that would produce the unexpected results.

Comment: Yes. Agree with you!!

Comment: what about third one $x=2. it will assign value to $x or not ??Is $x value changes ??

Comment: No. As the third expression only executes at the end of each iteration and there will be none in this case, it will not assign the value to `$x`.

Comment: Thanks @SougataBose

Comment: Where do I find this type of questions for practice with PHP ??@SougataBose

Comment: There is no fixed place for this. Its all about learning when you actually implementing and going through the Docs properly

Answer (score 0):

```
for($x++ ; $x==2 ; $x=2) 
    print "In the for loop" ; 
print "After the loop" ;
```

Its the correct indenting for these lines of code.

Here you can see that `print "In the for loop"` is indented for the loop. Secondly, if we have no scope for `loop` or `condition` then only very next one line will be part of that scope.